# How to use ON DELETE CASCADE with SQLite and Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, entity-framework-6

I can't get *ON DELETE CASCADE* work with SQLite and Entity Framework 6 (EF6). Is there anything I'm missing?

I created a Windows Forms application in C# with Visual Studio 2015. EF6 and SQLite were well working together in my application, I could insert and retrieve data. But when it comes to delete stuff, deleting one row/entity works fine but the cascade doesn't work at all. 
With *DB Browser for SQLite*, I deleted the exact same row, and the cascade worked.

This is my table which represents nodes:

```
CREATE TABLE `Nodes` (
    `NodeId`    INTEGER,
    `ParentId`  INTEGER,
    `Label` TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(`NodeId`),
    FOREIGN KEY(`ParentId`) REFERENCES `Nodes`(`NodeId`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

And this is how I'm deleting the "root" node (supposed to delete every child nodes with cascade):

```
var noParentItems = entities.Nodes.Where(n => n.ParentId == null);
foreach (var root in noParentItems)
{
     //entities.Entry(root).State = EntityState.Deleted;
     entities.Nodes.Remove(root);
}
entities.SaveChanges();
```

Notes: 
I also tried the commented version to delete "root".
Here you see that I am looping to catch every root nodes, but this is not important.

I am using the database-first approach for EF6. Please note that I don't want to modify any generated file to fix this.

Also, these solutions didn't work for me:

- [Entity Framework On Delete Cascade when entity is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31371786/entity-framework-on-delete-cascade-when-entity-is-loaded) : nothing changed
- Put "cascade" in the designer ( [How to delete a row with data with its parent row in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458917/how-to-delete-a-row-with-data-with-its-parent-row-in-another-table/37459049#37459049) ) : nothing changed
- Use "entities.Nodes.Attach(root);" as suggested in one of the answer below didn't work either

Please feel free to ask any additional information you may need.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34038321/2946329

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37459049/2946329

Comment: Well, I don't want to modify the generated files, and OnModelCreating() is overriden in a generated file. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank to comments, I found out how to solve this issue.

First I looked at this answer:
[Cascade on delete not cascading with EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674318/cascade-on-delete-not-cascading-with-ef)

The important part is this quote:

> The Entity Framework is actually an ADO.NET data provider that is
>   itself wrapping an ADO.NET data provider (SQLite, to be specific).
>   Normally, the Entity Framework will open a database connection
>   whenever it needs one; these automatically-opened connections are
>   automatically closed when the Entity Framework is finished with it.
>   This default behavior works well with SQL Server due to its ADO.NET
>   provider's connection pooling. However, it does not work well with
>   SQLite, due to various "properties" existing on the SQLite connection
>   itself. One example is "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON", which enforces
>   foreign keys only for that SQLite database connection. If the Entity
>   Framework opens and closes its connections at will, then SQLite
>   PRAGMAs such as these are lost.

So, if there is a place to put instructions, it would be only in the connection string.

Consequently I added this:

```
foreign keys=True
```

Now it works fine !

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `AsNoTracking` in your query, I know but  even so you can try like this;

```
foreach (var root in noParentItems)
{
     entities.Nodes.Attach(root);
     entities.Entry(root).State = EntityState.Deleted;
}
```

or like this;

```
foreach (var root in noParentItems)
{
     var newRoot = new Node{ NodeId = root.NodeId };
     entities.Nodes.Attach(newRoot);
     entities.Entry(newRoot).State = EntityState.Deleted;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first version didn't work. The version with var newRoot = new Nodes { NodeId = root.NodeId }; raised an exception probably because it creates an element with the same Primary Key. Here is the message: "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key."

Comment: Ohh my mistake. For second example would you add AsNoTracking() in your query and try again ?

Comment: To be honest I didn't hear about AsNoTracking() before. How should I use it?

Comment: Like this var noParentItems = entities.Nodes.AsNoTracking().Where(n => n.ParentId == null);

Comment: I wrote: `var noParentItems = entities.Nodes.AsNoTracking().Where(n => n.ParentId == null);

                foreach (var root in noParentItems)
                {
                    var newRoot = new Nodes { NodeId = root.NodeId };
                    entities.Nodes.Attach(newRoot);
                    entities.Entry(newRoot).State = EntityState.Deleted;
                }` but it didn't work (a single row was deleted).

Comment: I am sorry my friend. Unfortunately I don't have another suggestion :( but, I have found an article here. Did you read this; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674318/cascade-on-delete-not-cascading-with-ef